# Node Server not working with SSL

Tags: node.js, laravel, ssl, socket.io

I have a node server code on named **server.js**

```
var env = require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});
var fs = require("fs");
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(env.APP_SSL_PATH + 'server.key').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(env.APP_SSL_PATH + 'server.crt').toString()
};

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('https');
var server = http.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');


// Check if server is listening on its port 
server.listen(env.APP_NODE_PORT, function() {
  console.log('Listening on your port');

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("new client connected");
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    redisClient.subscribe('notification-channel', function(err, count) {
    });

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
      console.log( " message= "+ message + " channel = " + channel);
      socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      redisClient.quit();
    });

  });

});
```

Using *http* it works fine but then when I add the SSL certificate on *https* the code is not working already and it doesn't throw any error. I run the node server.js by

```
node server.js > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

there are no error log showing on *stderr.txt* file. Please help me Im new on this. On the console 
**Listening on your port** 
will logged only it does not continue and log 
**new client connected**

This is my client side code:

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('{{ env("APP_URL") }}:8890');
socket.on('notification-channel', function (data) {
  var header_count_elem = $('#menubar #header-messages-count');

  var count = header_count_elem.text();

  if (data != 'no-sound') {
    $.get('/notification/notif-alerts', function(response) {
      header_count_elem.text((response.count == '0') ? '' : response.count);

      if (data != 'no-sound') {
        if (count != response.count) {
           var sound = '<audio id="audioplayer" autoplay=true volume=1>' +
                '<source src="{{ url('assets/themes/cpanel/alarms/notification_sound.mp3') }}" type="audio/mpeg">' +
                '<source src="{{ url('assets/themes/cpanel/alarms/notification_sound.ogg')}}" type="audio/ogg">' +
                '</audio>';

          $('body').append(sound);
        }

      }

    });
  }

});
```

Comment: have you changed the url on your client side to https? Seems like there is no socket connection incoming

Comment: yes sir it is already on https

Comment: are you able to reach an express route with this setup?

Comment: What's the error you get client side when trying to connect? What's the client code look like?

Comment: @JohannesMerz yes sir Im able to listen on the port.. It does log "Listening on your port".

Comment: @user866762 it doesnt log any errors. On my client side code Ive updated my question. Thanks.